# Is it possible to denoise a baked texture?

Tags: texture-baking

Simple question, I bake a map, and I would like to use denoising on that texture. Is it possible in Blender?

I'm proceeding with various tests, using the Compositor, and the denoise node, I'm not very sure how you can (and if you can) do some sort of denoise of a bpy.data.images
I am quite confused, in this case I was thinking of using a situation like this:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). It's not currently possible, but it's a [requested feature](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Dgfbbc/) hopefully coming soon.

Comment: It was actually [in development](https://developer.blender.org/D3099) in 2018 but never included in a Blender release.

Comment: Ah, here, this is valuable information.
I was doing some tests, using the compositor, but if I add an image (That of the bake) and add the denoiser node, nothing happens. I thought the compositor would work on any image of type bpy.data.images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, using the node setup you show in your screen shot. The only thing you need is to open the image editor, set it to show the composite output or viewer node result. Then you will be able to save your picture using the menus or via <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.